# Plotting graph in R based on color bins

Tags: r

I have three columns: latitude, longitude, and price.
I want to plot a graph with x axis as lat, y axis as long. The color of the point is decided by the price value. (0-50$ - Red, 50-100$ blue etc). I tried using ggplots but did not find anything that can color the point based on the provided range.

```
latitude    longitude   price
40.8520537789   -73.7886796346  100
40.8411441603   -73.7830522867  100.4
40.8500238142   -73.7893275949  102
```

Comment: Use `cut()` or `findInterval()` on your `price` column first to get the groups.

Comment: I did that. Now I values 0,1,..9 (10 bins) in the price column. How would this solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plot() function for that.

Here is the data.table (or alternatively, you can use data.frame as well)

```
> dt
   latitude longitude price
1: 40.85205 -73.78868 100.0
2: 40.84114 -73.78305 100.4
3: 40.85002 -73.78933 102.0
```

You can find out the color for each row by the following code.

```
color_val <- ifelse(dt[['price']] >= 0 & dt[['price']] <= 50,"red",ifelse(dt[['price']] > 50 & dt[['price']] <= 100,"blue","black"))
```

or by the method as mentioned by @thelatemail:

```
cut(dt$price, c(0,50,100,Inf), labels=c("red","blue","black"))
```

Now, you can plot the data by this command:

```
plot(x = dt[['latitude']],y = dt[['longitude']],col = color_val)
```

Note: This is just normal plotting on x-y coordinates.

Comment: All of that `ifelse` coding could be reduced to `cut(dt$price, c(0,50,100,Inf), labels=c("red","blue","black"))`